# <td> items gets messed up after changing display using js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im having a problem where using js to change the display of a  element, the whole thing seem to get squeezed into 1 cell (expanding the other cell in other row). Here is the codepen for what is described

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/dontaskm8/pen/dxqmOP)

`formTable.rows[i+2].style.display = 'none'
    }else{
 formTable.rows[i+2].style.display = 'block'`

if i would to hide each of the cells in all of the rows, the cells end up displaying vertically if they are set to be blocked.

I want it to show only the selected row/column from the list of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next one

```
if(config == false){
  formTable.rows[i+2].style.display = 'none';
}else{
  formTable.rows[i+2].style.display = 'table-row';
}
```

You set `display` property to `block` but it should be a `table-row` for corrert presentation of table.

More details https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/#article-header-id-10

Comment: omg that worked. Didnt know that table needs a different display type. One new thing to learn